# WSO2 Get UserInfo return an error java null exception

Tags: java, apache, wso2, identityserver4

I have been setup an identity server using wso2 and already got a token, but when I used the token to get userinfo I get an internal server error.

request body to get token.

```
grant_type=password&username=erwin&password=admin&scope=openid
```

token result

```
    {
      "access_token": "9689f5f4-8ba0-398c-91d0-46dfac85b64a",
      "refresh_token": "497e57a4-21ff-3dca-a97f-687446c25321",
      "scope": "openid",
      "id_token": "eyJ4NXQiOiJOVEF4Wm1NeE5ETXlaRGczTVRVMVpHTTBNekV6T0RKaFpXSTRORE5sWkRVMU9HRmtOakZpTVEiLCJraWQiOiJOVEF4Wm1NeE5ETXlaRGczTVRVMVpHTTBNekV6T0RKaFpXSTRORE5sWkRVMU9HRmtOakZpTVEiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdF9oYXNoIjoiU0U4OVRxTkt2U3JWSWRnVXk2eE5XQSIsImFjciI6InVybjptYWNlOmluY29tbW9uOmlhcDpzaWx2ZXIiLCJzdWIiOiJlcndpbiIsImF1ZCI6WyJuU08xSTQyZ043a1JYZE9CdXdZbXNBMTdDY29hIl0sImF6cCI6Im5TTzFJNDJnTjdrUlhkT0J1d1ltc0ExN0Njb2EiLCJpc3MiOiJsb2NhbGhvc3QiLCJleHAiOjE1MTUwMzM3NDQsImlhdCI6MTUxNTAzMDE0NH0.Vz5K38k3UivwayYQWQVO86njwI48I5KpZiEqwrXethIZQ990JYZ1U6MiFEuKzA5Z3AZkDH2_HmHQeTSrjb7GUlIwejOtl7ky6Wc6uAD3a6YidWHAb1BLygX91KNwYdmgZ5ReyrJyZQ5Vri1qOhFfPFHKzkTgyKFZtJDDNvQ_SL8MxyaPer4rneEziXyYxZKJ0RrTnhOJVQ-TE0TxszlvNW4wAzmk_eVu9JDEycJdwAo1GS4U8tjqJPrMRdZNp371rS_-HHa5oSl-wVCEswtsKEoV5UeqKIeJoj0yGIFRqJxhpY9yxMSn-6jeviRBh40QstDNxFeluDpC8B6o7YIzmA",
      "token_type": "Bearer",
      "expires_in": 3594
    }
```

And I use that access token to get user info,

```
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid  
Authorization : Bearer 9689f5f4-8ba0-398c-91d0-46dfac85b64a
Method : GET
```

The Result is error

```
    Exception report

message org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
    org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:336)
    ...

root cause

org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
    org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:170)
    ...

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.wso2.carbon.identity.openidconnect.AbstractUserInfoResponseBuilder.getRequestObject(AbstractUserInfoResponseBuilder.java:298)
    ...
```

Comment: Is this IS 5.4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is already reported for IS 5.4.0.

https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/1953

Comment: Thx bee, yes this is IS 5.4.0

Comment: Bee, Can you tell me, how to implement that fixed version? Am I need to replace my WSO version 5.4.0 to update 3?

Comment: Clone tag `5.5.168` of https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth and apply the fix in https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/pull/752/files. Then build the jar and replace the same jar in `<IS_HOME>/repository/components/plugins/`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in the master branch of https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth.

Comment: Thx hasanthi. Im sorry, can you explain how to implement that fixed source on my source?